# How to select userIds that have same siteId throughout the 5 hrs of time period?

Tags: sql, impala

I have the following table,

| userId | siteId | logged_time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 100001 | 7890 | 31-01-2021 11:55 |
| 100002 | 7878 | 31-01-2021 12:27 |
| 100001 | 7890 | 01-02-2021 01:05 |
| 100004 | 7878 | 01-02-2021 11:55 |
| 100002 | 7848 | 01-02-2021 11:30 |
| 100001 | 7890 | 02-02-2021 13:34 |

What I need to do is, select all users where they have logged on to the same site for 5 hrs of first logging. My current approach is

- get each user's first `logged_time` and add 5 hours to it.
- grab all the results of each user that belong to 5 hours interval.
- get the distinct `siteId` count for each user
- If distinct `siteId` count for each user equals 1 then grab those users else reject that user

I think my approach is quite good. But I can't figure out how to do that using impala and SQL.
Any help would be highly appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: Use WHERE NOT EXISTS.

Comment: Hi, @Akina could you explain a little bit about how can I accomplish that using EXISTS. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM src t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT NULL
                   FROM src t2
                   WHERE t1.userId = t2.userId
                     AND t1.siteId != t2.siteId
                     AND t2.logged_time BETWEEN logged_time 
                                            AND logged_time + INTERVAL 5 HOUR )
```

Comment: How would it check for the first login of user? Curious to know.

Comment: @Popeye Why first only? OP tells: *What I need to do is, select all users where they have logged on to the same site for 5 hrs of first logging.* Nothing about first login or even distinct users list. I think that *where* is used errorneously, and *when* must be used... From the other side, further explanations generally make the task incomprehensible. They require you to delete the user... despite the fact that previously it could have been selected as meeting the described conditions.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend window functions for this:

```
select userid
from (select t.*,
             min(logged_time) over (partition by userid) as min_logged_time
      from t
     ) t
where logged_time < min_logged_time + interval '5 hour'
group by userid
having min(siteid) = max(siteid);
```

I would note that this actually answers your question by returning users with no duplicates.  I would also expect window functions to be faster than alternative methods.